# ios - sending data to NSOperation or should I use NSThread?

Tags: ios, concurrency

I have core data objects that are created/updated via HTTP. I also want to create a background thread to continuously receive timestamp and state info from the app and update the core data objects.  Should I use NSOperation or GCD for this? Since it's not just a simple task, NSOperation seems better since I can loop within it, but I can't figure out how to pass information into the operation, from the main thread, while it's running. Is there a simple way of doing this? I have seen many threads/articles about sending messages to the main thread from the operation, but nothing about passing messages to it.

Does using NSOperation/GCD seem like a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Step back and relook at your architecture. You should be using a managed object context that itself uses a private dispatch queue (option NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType).

You would then use NSURLConnections to get the data you want, and when you get the data in the delegate method you can asynchronously update the repository using `performBlock`.

Conversely you may want to retrieve data using `performBlockAndWait`, using block variables or mutable pre-defined objects to receive the results from the block.

Comment: I'm doing this when fetching the data.  What I need is a separate process to update the data based on application state.  So, I fetch the data and use `performBlock` and save the data in the managed object context.  The app broadcasts state info and the core data entities need to be updated separately, based on calculations of the broadcasted state.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - you can always update the Core Data using performBlock. At the very end of an "update", have the performBlock do one more thing - like queue a block on your main queue to update UI elements that may be visible. If you have other needs for processing - perhaps extracting data from Core Data, you can use performBlock with those too and in the end queue the block on the main thread. Do you really need another queue to do work on? If so create a queue, post work on it, and when all is done send a block to the main queue to update the UI. Do not suggest using NSOperation.

Comment: I've figured it out... the problem is that I come from a java background and was thinking of subclassing NSThread and needing to pass data to it from the main thread.  I was trying to avoid using blocks (I'm used to encapsulating everything in separate classes/files).  I think I was making this more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this all wrong (essentially wanting to subclass NSThread and pass data to/from it).  I didn't think about using blocks appropriately.

Essentially, what I'm doing is:

```
loadStuff:(NSDictionary *)stuff {
    // stuff is data from HTTP GET request
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = // init context with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType
    context.parentContext = // main context
    [context performBlock:^{
        // insert/update entities
        // save context
    }];
}
```

But then I need to loop in a background thread to update the entities:

```
//inside some method
dispatch_async(global_queue, ^{
    // _currentTimestamp is updated by a delegate
    NSInterval timestamp = _currentTimestamp;
    while (run) {
        if (timestamp != _currentTimestamp) {
            // do calculation
            // update entities if needed
            // save context
        }
    }
});
```